# Amazon Web Services - Relational Database Service - Security Scan

Tags: databases, amazon, scan

My company is utilizing AWS for it's infrastructure including Mysql RDS instances for our databases. Everything we have is in a VPC and requires access through our VPN. Our databases are all not accessible to the public and on private subnets.

Despite this we currently have a request from a customer to comply with a security audit of our systems. Included in this audit is a database security scan.

However, the only available scanning tool in the AWS marketplace is Nessus which is only capable of scanning EC2 instances that are not micro or small. I have asked AWS support if they knew of any tool that I can use to scan the database and the support engineer did not know of any.

I have also asked, but have yet to receive an answer, if they provide results of security scans that they may run internally or provide documentation to the fact that they scan their servers and remediate any vulnerabilities. I have made this request through both their support team and the compliance request form located here: http://aws.amazon.com/compliance/contact/. Which put me in contact with a sales representative not capable of answering my questions or helping me achieve success in our client's demand. I have also tried to provide the risk assessment whitepaper provided by AWS but that was deemed insufficient.

I also confess that I am not an IT security professional and work for a small company where I must wear many hats so I am not proficient in the security jargon. I have read through the compliance page briefly and have noticed that AWS RDS does not appear to be HIPA or FedRAMP compliant but honestly don't think that should apply to my organization because we retain no sensitive information in our database. We also prefer to not move our database out of AWS RDS since we utilize multi-az functionality.

So now given the back story, I am still left fruitless in my search to provide attestation in the form of security scans of our databases. My question would be to those out there that have had to comply with such requests specifically with AWS RDS and security. How have you met the demand of your client by providing for such a scan?

Comment: are we to assume that your instances are all micro or small?

Comment: Only our dev RDS is a micro all others are xlarge. However, Nessus cannot even scan an RDS.

Comment: Can Nessus not scan remote hosts? Spin up a medium instance or use on of the xlarge that has access to the RDS and specify its address as the remote host when scanning?

Comment: Not sure how this would be accomplished using the AWS version of Nessus. I have created a policy that has the necessary credentials for a specific AWS RDS (s is for service you cannot actually ssh to anything) instance but I am forced when creating a scan to select an EC2 instance. The scan will discover the open port for the database but won't actually try to connect to the database to scan it. Not having any luck with AWS or Tenable on how to fulfill this request.